# SSL Error while connecting messenger API with letsencypt

Tags: java, nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt

I am trying to connect to a service from messenger API, I am getting following error.

SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I have used LetsEncrypt as HTTPS certificate issuer.

This is my config for NGINX : -

```
server {
    listen ip:80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name example.com;

    listen ip:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

location / {
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        #https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/504-gateway-time-out-using-nginx/
        proxy_connect_timeout       600;
        proxy_send_timeout          600;
        proxy_read_timeout          600;
        send_timeout                600;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8083/;
        index  index.html ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you copy pasted this or you ran Certbot?

Answer (score 0):

try this configuration format. I think it gonna help to you.

```
server {
    listen example.com:80;

    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen www.example.com:80;

    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name  example.com;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        root /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/index.html; #your index.html path
        index index.html;
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```